# How to rowspan for table third column?

Tags: angularjs, html

How to rowspan for third column. Trying to create table with three columns but it didn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/c47xK/619/

```
angular.module('App',[]);
angular.module('App').controller('MyCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.groups = [{
        "id":1,
        "members":[
            {"name":"Sue", "friend":[{"frend": "100"},{"frend": "200"}]},
            {"name":"Jane","friend":[{"frend": "300"},{"frend": "400"}]},
            {"name":"Edna","friend":[{"frend": "500"},{"frend": "600"}, {"frend": "700"}]}
        ]
    },{
        "id":2,
        "members":[

            {"name":"James","friend":[{"frend": "800"},{"frend": "900"}, {"frend": "1000"}]}
        ]
    }];
});
```

Comment: Id 1 should span Sue, Jane and Edna and

Comment: name "Sue" should span "friend" 100 and 200

Answer (score 0):

Very tricky and interesting problem! Not sure how you can achieve this using table. But it possible to to display in table format using css.

```
<div class="row border" ng-repeat="group in groups">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      {{group.id}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10 border">
      <div class="row border"  ng-repeat="member in group.members">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div>{{member.name}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="border" ng-repeat="friend in member.friend">{{friend.frend}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Working [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/gilango/5v8ucxb1/) for your reference. Interested to know about other solutions if you find any!

Comment: there is overlap of borders and not consistent with entire arch. Any idea how rowspan can be used in 2nd column for spanning third column?